# How to dynamically change DataTemplate according to bound object's type?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, datatemplate

I'm trying to create a DataTemplate for a View, to show a specific UserControl type (like a texbox, combobox, custom control or another View) based on the type of object it is bound to.

I have the following MVVM framework:

`FieldView` is tied to an instance of `FieldPresenter`, and should display a `<Textblock />` for the "Label" property, and a UserControl or another View for the Value (based on the Type of the value), with it's DataSource set to the Value property of the Presenter. Currently, I do not have the second part working. I can't figure out how to write a WPF template for what I need.

ViewModel:

```
public class FieldPresenter : Observable<object>, IFieldPresenter, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public FieldPresenter() { }
    public FieldPresenter(object value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }
    object IFieldPresenter.Value
    {
        get
        {
            return base.Value;
        }

        set
        {
            base.Value = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Value");
        }
    }
    private string _label;
    public virtual string Label
    {
        get
        {
            return _label;
        }
        private set
        {
            _label = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Label");
        }
    }
}
```

View:

```
<UserControl x:Class="My.Views.FieldView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:ViewModels="clr-namespace:My.ViewModels"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="24" d:DesignWidth="100">
    <UserControl.DataContext>
        <ViewModels:FieldPresenter/>
    </UserControl.DataContext>
        <UserControl.Template>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Grid Margin="4">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="Key" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Grid}, Path=ActualWidth}">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Label}" FontWeight="Bold" Height="32" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding Value}" Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </UserControl.Template>
</UserControl>
```

I'm curious if what I'm trying to do is even possible, or if I can workaround it by making my Presenter viewmodel return a UserControl rather than an object value, and have the Presenter parse the UserControl Type from the object type, but I don't feel like my Presenter should be instantiating Controls (or what is technically an unbound view). Should I make an interface, something like `IViewAs<controlType> { controlType View { get; } }`?

How else would I replace `<TextBox Text="{Binding Value}" />` in the above script with some kind of template of a UserControl based on the databound object's type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You almost certainly want a `ContentTemplateSelector` :

Code:

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Primitive primitive;

            primitive = new Sphere();
            //  primitive = new Cube();
            DataContext = primitive;
        }
    }

    internal abstract class Primitive
    {
        public abstract string Description { get; }
    }

    internal class Cube : Primitive
    {
        public override string Description
        {
            get { return "Cube"; }
        }
    }

    internal class Sphere : Primitive
    {
        public override string Description
        {
            get { return "Sphere"; }
        }
    }

    public class MyTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
    {
        public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
        {
            var frameworkElement = container as FrameworkElement;
            if (frameworkElement != null && item != null)
            {
                if (item is Cube)
                {
                    return frameworkElement.FindResource("CubeTemplate") as DataTemplate;
                }
                if (item is Sphere)
                {
                    return frameworkElement.FindResource("SphereTemplate") as DataTemplate;
                }
            }

            return base.SelectTemplate(item, container);
        }
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        x:Name="Window"
        Title="MainWindow"
        Width="525"
        Height="350"
        mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid>
        <Grid.Resources>
            <local:MyTemplateSelector x:Key="myTemplateSelector" />
            <DataTemplate x:Key="CubeTemplate" DataType="local:Cube">
                <Border BorderBrush="Blue"
                        BorderThickness="1"
                        CornerRadius="5" />
            </DataTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:Key="SphereTemplate" DataType="local:Sphere">
                <Border BorderBrush="Red"
                        BorderThickness="1"
                        CornerRadius="50" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </Grid.Resources>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Label Grid.Row="0"
               Content="{Binding Description}"
               d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance local:Primitive}" />
        <ContentControl Grid.Row="1"
                        Content="{Binding}"
                        ContentTemplateSelector="{StaticResource myTemplateSelector}" />

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Result:

[image]

[image]

See the documentation for more:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datatemplateselector(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: The `ContentTemplateSelector` is completely unnecessary in this answer, the only reason it's needed here is because the `DataType` bindings haven't been declared properly. Delete the `ContentTemplateSelector` from the resources block, remove `ContentTemplateSelector="{StaticResource myTemplateSelector}"`, change `<DataTemplate x:Key="CubeTemplate" DataType="local:Cube">` to `<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Cube}">` and change `<DataTemplate x:Key="SphereTemplate" DataType="local:Sphere">` to `<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Sphere}">`. The code will work exactly the same.

Comment: You're right but doing so will invariably assign the same template over and over for the same type, the OP for instance could specify specific template names through some mechanism, he'd be able to keep control of assigning different templates for the same type (should he need such thing) :)